# "other" from drop down menu, html

Tags: php, html

I have a form in html that takes the inputs and does some calculations. What I would like to do is have a drop down menu that has some options, but if the user's option isn't there, they can enter their own.

For this example let's assume it takes the sum of all the entries:

```
<form action="action.php">
    <input type="text" name="int1" value="1">
    <select name="dropdown">
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="NULL">Other</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="other" value="other">
    <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

My idea is that it would use either the drop down menu, or the "other" input if the drop down is set to other. Is there a way to care care of this in html or is this done with an if statement in php? just some of my ideas.

Help appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do something like

```
if (isset($_GET['dropdown']) 
    && $_GET['dropdown'] == 'NULL'
    && isset($_GET['other'])
) {
    $value = $_GET['other'];
}
elseif (isset($_GET['dropdown'])) {
    $value = $_GET['dropdown'];
}
else {
    // Something went wrong. Handle error
}
```

You could also use JavaScript to submit the form so that only one value is passed to PHP if you're looking for a client-side solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using jquery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<html><body>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="int1" value="1">
    <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="NULL">Other</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="other" value="other" id="other">
    <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
</body></html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#other").hide();
        $('#dropdown').change(function(){

            if($(this).val()=='NULL'){
                $("#other").show();
            }
            else{
                $("#other").hide();
            }
        }); 
})
</script>
```

and use php to catch the correct value

Answer (score 0):

I would embed a PHP statement there that says if dropdown value is equal to other then add input text field under drop down box for user input.